# Unable to display PIL Image inside Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to display a `PIL.Image` inside a `tkinter.Canvas`:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x400')
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=400)
canvas.pack()
pilImage = Image.open("pillow.png")
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
imagesprite = canvas.create_image(400,400,image=image)
root.mainloop()
```

But when I run this code only a void window appears, without the image.
How can I solve this problem?

I'm using Python 3.4.1 on OS X 10.9

Comment: Works on my Windows machine. Maybe OSX is different. Have you read the note at the bottom of [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) page? I doubt it applies here, but it couldn't hurt to try.

Comment: I find that it works on my OS X machine, so I don't think it's a purely platform issue